# checkbox not working in single click in Jstree plugin in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

```
   treeData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    var determinedStatus = false;
                    $.each(treeData, function (k, v) {
                        if (v.flag == true) {
                            classClicked = "jstree-clicked";
                        } else if (v.flag == false) {
                            classClicked = '';
                        }
                        if (setUndeterminedStatus(v.id)) {
                            determinedStatus = true;
                            classClicked = "jstree-undetermined";
                        }
                        currentTree.push({
                            "id": v.id,
                            "text": v.text,
                            "parent": v.parent,
                            "a_attr": {"data-original-title": v.comment, "class": classClicked},
                            "state": {"undetermined": determinedStatus}
                        });
                    });
                    $('#jstree_demo_div').jstree({
                        'plugins': ["types", "checkbox"],
                        'checkbox': {"three_state": true},
                        'core': {
                            "themes": {
                                "variant": "large"
                            },
                            "check_callback": true,
                            'data': currentTree
                        }
                    });
```

I am able to render the data through ajax request but while unchecking the checkbox its not working in single click. I need to click double click to uncheck or check the checkboxes.
        I am sending the ajax request and storing data in variable and passing variable in jstree data.

If I am doing anything wrong.. Please advice me to make it correct.
Thanks in advance.